# div oval shape with corner with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a shape like the image.

[image]

I'm trying to use border radius css but all I get is a semi-circle.
Can any body help me?

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS as a stack snippet in your question to show your attempt so far and what you're currently getting.

Comment: Yes, do post your code for specific help. Just wanted to say [this tutorial](https://medium.com/9elements/css-border-radius-can-do-that-d46df1d013ae) covers the details of making complex or unusual shapes with border-radius.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The tutorial posted by @RutherfordWonkington was very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pseudo element to create this. The trick is to have a small overlap and you don't color that overlap:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before,
.box:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:70%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:red;
  background-clip:content-box; /* Don't color the padding */
}
.box:before {
  left:0;
  padding-right:20%; /* (70% - 50%)*/
  border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
}
.box:after {
  right:0;
  padding-left:20%;
  border-radius: 0 150px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Then you can make the other sides to overflow and you will have the shape you want:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box:before,
.box:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:80%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:red;
  background-clip:content-box;
}
.box:before {
  left:-10%;
  padding-right:20%;
  border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
}
.box:after {
  right:-10%;
  padding-left:20%;
  border-radius: 0 150px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

---

Here is another idea using multiple background:

```css
.box {
  width:130px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle 90px at -20px             100%, red 98%,transparent 100%) top right/50% 90px,
    radial-gradient(circle 90px at calc(100% + 20px) 100%, red 98%,transparent 100%) top left /50% 90px,
    linear-gradient(red,red) bottom/100% calc(100% - 80px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```